# trying to compile simple inotify program

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to compile inotify simpe code on Ubuntu 6.06.2 with kernel version 2.6.15.
my code is

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define IN_NONBLOCK O_NONBLOCK


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        char buf;
        int fd, i, poll_num;
        int *wd;
        nfds_t nfds;
        struct pollfd fds[2];

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("Usage: %s PATH [PATH ...]\n", argv[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("Press ENTER key to terminate.\n");

        /* Create the file descriptor for accessing the inotify API */

        fd = inotify_init();
        if (fd == -1) {
                perror("inotify_init1");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


        close(fd);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have installed libc6-dev 2.3.6 also.
but when i compile this code got

```
error: sys/inotify.h: No such file or directory
```

and when I use linux/inotify.h than i got

```
/tmp/ccUTUEAq.o: In function `main':ionotify.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `inotify_init'.
```

please someone tell me how i can resolve this issue.

Comment: `Inotify was merged into the 2.6.13 Linux kernel.  The required  library interfaces were added to glibc in version 2.4. (IN_DONT_FOLLOW, IN_MASK_ADD, and IN_ONLYDIR were added in glib version 2.5.)`. So I think that you need libc update

Comment: Looking at [the `inotify_init` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_init.2.html) it says that support was added to glibc 2.4. You need to upgrade your (very old!) system.

Comment: thanks for quick response..

Comment: @pbn Don't use comment markdown for emphasize!

Answer (score -2):

inotify.h must be present in the system path.

i.e /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/inotify.h

sys/inotify.h is not part of the standard library! (It is, however, part of the libraries typically available on a linux box)

Comment: how i can make this "/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/inotify.h" path in ubuntu.should  i have install some package or library for this